# C++ Double subscript overloading: cannot convert from 'type' to 'type &'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, subscript-operator

I'm trying to make a 2D matrix class which is actually a vector of vectors and both classes are templates. I've overloaded the subscript operator in the **vector** class. The problem occurs when I try to overload operator[] in **matrix** class with the error message:
*error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'vector' to 'vector &'*.
Here's code from my classes:

```
template <typename t>
class vector
{
private:
    t           *Mem;
    int         vectsize;

public:
    vector<t>   (int _vectsize = 0);
    //some other methods here
    t& operator[](int index)
    {
            return Mem[index];
    }
};
```

And

```
template <typename h>
class matrix
{
private:
    int dim;
    vector< vector<h> > *Mat;

public:
    matrix<h> (int _dim = 0);

    matrix<h> (const matrix & _copy);

    vector<h>& operator[](int index)
    {
        return Mat[index];  //Here's the error
    }
};
```

I made some googling and found the same examples or overloading () instead of []. I just can't understand why compiler can't see returned value *Mat[index]* as a reference (which I believe must be a reference). When working with a single vector the subscript operator works just fine though. Please, point me to my mistake(s). Thanks in advance!

Added: using non-dynamic vector seems to solve the current problem, but instead of types' mismatch I've got two linker errors (unresolved external symbol). By commenting and decommenting my code I found that the problem occurs only if the line `vector< vector<h> > Mat;` or `Extend` function is present (it's an empty method from class vector). I guess there's something to do with **vector** constructor, but I do not know what exactly is wrong.

```
template <typename t> //vector constructor
vector<t>::vector(int _vectsize)
    {
        vectsize = _vectsize;
        Mem = new t[vectsize];
        for (int i=0; i<vectsize; i++)
            Mem[i] = 0;
    }
```

In matrix.h (it's not in separate files yet):

```
matrix<h> (int _dim = 0) : Mat(_dim)
    {
        dim = _dim;
        for (int i=0; i<dim; i++)
            Mat[i].Extend(dim-i);
    }
```

I'd love to hear any suggestions, if possible.

Comment: Mat is pointer, so to fix this compile error, I believe you need to write `return *Mat[index]`, or change Mat type to vector.

Comment: I thought so, but adding an asterisk did not solve the problem (error C2100: illegal indirection). I'll try then to use the non-dynamic vector.

Answer (score 2):

`Mat` is a pointer to a vector. There is no reason to allocate dynamically a vector, just use `vector<vector<H>> Mat;`.

Also, `operator[]` has commonly two overloads: One const to read, and one non-const to write:

```
//Read overload
const T& operator[](std::size_t index) const 
{
    return /* blah blah */
}

//Write overload
T& operator[](std::size_t index) 
{
    return /* blah blah */
}
```

This allows to read the vector in const contexts.

Answer (score 0):

`Mat` is a `vector< vector<h> >*`, not a `vector< vector<h> >`. Therfore, `Mat[index]` does not call `vector::operator[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector< vector<h> > *Mat;
```

why do you have pointer? You don't need it. It should be simply a `vector` of `vector<h>`.

```
vector< vector<h> > Mat;
```

note: it's just a convention, but use uppercase names for template arguments, otherwise others going to hate you ;)

Comment: Huh, ok! :-) I'm just a beginner. Seems like I need to learn all those ethic rules.

Comment: it has nothing to do with ethics. and it has nothing to do with the language. the compiler (as you can see) doesn't care. WE care. it's easier to read something which was formatted in a familiar way. that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, guys, my problem has been solved. In order to avoid weird errors while initializing matrix it's definitely better to use non-dynamic vector like in examples above. Linker errors have been fixed by copy-pasting functions' definitions in header file (from vector.cpp to vector.h). It could be done through including .cpp file in header file as well. Strange, but single vector worked perfectly with separated files, that's why I didn't ever consider this as the source of the problem.